# OneSignal - Where to find the "Advanced options section" of an existing project

Tags: onesignal

I'm new to OneSignal but managed to get it set up on one of my live sites. Now I'm trying to set it up for testing on localhost and I'm stuck with the "wrong origin" Chrome Dev Tools error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: OneSignal: This web push config can only be used on https://localhost. Your current origin is http://localhost:8080`.

I tried to follow the [docs'](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-setup-faq#section-how-do-i-test-my-site-on-a-local-environment-) instructions, but one of the criteria that one has to adhere to in order for OneSignal to recognize localhost as a secure origin is this:

> - For Typical Site integrations: Enable "Treat HTTP localhost as HTTPS for testing" in the Advanced options section of the web config editor.

The problem is that I can't find the "Advanced options section" for my OneSignal test app. From the dashboard I selected my app then went: Settings (in the navbar) > All Browsers (the only active platform) > Save (not editing anything on this page, as nothing needs updating). Then on the next page, section 5 is supposed to be the "Advanced options section" according to [this](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-options) docs article, but instead it's labelled as "Add your first user" and gives one a link that redirects to one's website.

My thinking is that either that second docs article is outdated and is showing the wrong information, or the "Advanced options section" is only available the first time you set up your app (although I don't remember seeing it during the setup, which is also why I haven't tried deleting and recreating my app).

If anyone knows how to 1) navigate the site to get to the "Advanced options section" and/or 2) get a testing app up and running in OneSignal, I'd greatly appreciate it.

**Notes:**

- In my client-side HTML initialization code, I already set the option `allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true`, which is a requirement to get this working. This alone is apparently not enough (not surprised).
- My OneSignal app uses the `Custom Code` integration type. (If what I'm trying to do can't be done because of this integration please let me know).
- In the error I posted in my first paragraph, I says it's looking for the domain `https://localhost`, but I'm instead providing it with `http://localhost:8080`. It worries me a little that it mentions the port number at the end of the host that I'm providing. If this is going to cause issues, even after I solve this initial problem, please let me know.

Please let me know if there's any other information I need to post.

Answer (score 0):

The OneSignal dashboard Site URL field needs to have the same origin as your actual site. Your site is found at `http://localhost:8080` but you have `http://localhost` in your Site URL field. Simply updating this value should fix the issue.

If you are still having a hard time, you can follow these instructions to provide the SDK debug logs to OneSignal support: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-web-push#section-debugging-using-browser-developer-tools

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. The reason I'm not putting in `http` as the protocol is that, and I quote from your docs, "Chrome treats http://localhost and http://127.0.0.1 as secure origins, allowing HTTPS integrations even on HTTP". My production environment uses https, thus I need to use the HTTPS SDK there, thus I also need the HTTPS SDK in development, if that makes sense? Now if I try to change my URL to http, it automatically checks the "my site is not fully https" button which has me thinking that I'm gonna end up using the HTTP SDK, which is completely the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to enable the flag Local Testing.
Please, beware that the *app ID* may change so be sure to copy the new one after you continue with the app configuration.

[image]